# Advanced options not available when exporting a phar in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, phar

- My ultimate task:

  Generate a phar (php archive) from Eclipse and make its contents
  unavailable (source code) when importing it into another PHP project.
- Notes:

  I am new to phar (been studying it since yesterday only). I have
  already searched the mighty internet for answers; it seems most of
  the solutions for building a phar involves writing code and I do not
  want to do that. It appears that I can use the phar
  [manifest](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.phar.php) to
  setup the file permissions.
- My problem:

  In Eclipse I click on Export... / Phar export, which displays a
  window to setup my options. According to this
  [site](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/phar/tasks-35.htm),
  configuring the manifest is done after you click Next. However, Next
  button is not available no matter what I do.
- Question is:

  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!